# Is it true that $cl_{\beta X} Z(f) = Z(\hat f)$?

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Suppose $f\in C^* (X)$ and let $\hat f$ be its continuous extension to $\beta X$. It is clear that

$cl_{\beta X} Z(f)=cl_{\beta X} f^{-1}(${$0$}$)\subseteq \hat f ^{-1}(${$0$}$)= Z(\hat f)$, but I am having some difficulty showing the reverse inclusion.

Comment: What are $C^*(X)$ and $Z(f)$?  I assume $\beta X$ is the Stone-Cech compactification and $cl$ denotes closure.

Comment: Continuous bounded functions on X, and Zero set of f.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessarily true.  Consider, for instance, $X=(0,1)$, and $f(x) = x$.  Then $Z(f) = \emptyset$, but $Z(\hat{f})$ is not empty; for instance, the set $\{\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{3}, \frac{1}{4}, \dots\}$ has a limit point $y \in \beta X$ by compactness, and by continuity we must have $\hat{f}(y) = 0$.